# WCF via HTTP GET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service which I'm trying to access via a browser. It works fine via the test client, but my breakp[oints are not called when using a browser. My web.config has

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:84/BillService.svc"
            binding="webHttpBindingConfig" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBillService"
            behaviorConfiguration="json"
            contract="iBillService.IBillService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IBillService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="Behavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="json">
            <webHttp/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <!-- turn off authentication in WCF, we get the client from the HttpContext -->
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBasicAuth">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBillService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WsHttpBindingConfig">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webHttpBindingConfig">
            <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  <!-- to enable IIS authentication for WCF, we have to switch to compatibility mode -->
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService"
             behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomBasicAuth"
                contract="IWcfService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My interface definition has this:

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, Method:="GET")>
<WebGet(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Function GetBills(ByVal userName As String, ByVal passwordHash As String) As List(Of Bill)
```

Yet when I visit the URL

```
http://localhost:84/BillService.svc/GetBills?userName=demo&passwordHash=dummy
```

I get a blank page and my breakpoints aren't triggered

Comment: where is the definition for your <serviceBehaviors> ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be in your code, but in your annotations. WCF can get very frustrating since there are a lot of switches your can turn on and off. Start by adding a

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

to you service implementation. If you still don't see any error, you can enable WCF tracing:
[MSDN: Configuring WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

For WCF Tracing:

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
             <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                     switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                     propagateActivity="true">
                  <listeners>
                       <add name="traceListener" 
                            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                            initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
                  </listeners>
             </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be logged, either via the browser or the test client.

Comment: Yes, amoung other configurations mentioned on that page, I have this in my configuration header: <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="All, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">

Comment: The listener-element aswell? Just want to be safe. I'll edit my question, for the complete configuration section.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my configuration to this, but nothing is written. The file is not created when I invoke the service with the test client.

Comment: Is this a MVC application? The route to the service might be handled by the MVC controller factory rather than WCF.

Comment: @J.Tihon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1209/discussion-between-echilon-and-j-tihon)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<endpoint address=""
binding="basicHttpBinding"
bindingConfiguration="CustomBasicAuth"
contract="IWcfService" />
```

to

```
<endpoint address=""
binding="webHttpBinding"
bindingConfiguration="CustomBasicAuth"
contract="IWcfService" />
```

this might help you access your service using URL

Comment: You also need to use the <webHttp> behavior, so change it to <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="json" />. Also, is the name of the service class just "WcfService"? You need the fully-qualified name (the same value used in the BillService.svc) for the configuration to work.